# Apache2 mod_dav_svn SVNListParentPath dependent on cilent IP / subnet?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, networking, security, svn

Hopefully a simple question. Given the following Apache 2.2 VirtualHost configuration on a local network server with access from the local network and the internet:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName svn

    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /svn/repositories
        SVNListParentPath on

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion"
        AuthUserFile svn-auth-file
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible to flag on and off the "SVNListParentPath" directive dependent on client IP?

For example, if the client IP is on the 192.168.0.0/24 network I would like "SVNListParentPath on", if the client IP is any other network I would like "SVNListParentPath off" (default).

Current environment is Apache 2.2.x, Subversion 1.7.x on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you upgrade to 2.4? If or Elseif should do the trick.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins Apache 2.4 is maybe possible, depending on package availability within Ubuntu. All the server does (virtual machine) is SVN so upgrades and changes are possible. Are you able to give a sample configuration as a possible answer to this question?